# Sql Server compact database with linq-to-sql in visual studio 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-ce

How to use Linq-to-SQL with a sql server compact database in visual studio 2010 ?

thanks

Comment: You may read this article: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-linq-sql-sql-server, http://matthewmanela.com/blog/sql-ce-3-5-with-linq-to-sql-revisited. Try some code. This may clear your concept about SQLCE.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22342/LINQ-Challenges-and-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition

Comment: Thanks Guys :) @afshin
I wasn't able to create the dbml file.. i managed to do that with a work arround (using sqlMetal)..
do u know a better way ??